# Do Ruby 'require' statements go inside or outside the class definition?

Tags: ruby, object

When using class files in Ruby, do you put the 'requires' statements at the top of the file, or inside the class definition?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Technically, it doesn't really matter. `require` is just a normal method call, and the scope it's called in doesn't affect how it works. The only difference placement makes is that it will be executed when whatever code it's placed in is evaluated.

Practically speaking, you should put them at top so people can see the file's dependencies at a glance. That's the traditional place for it.

Comment: Does that mean that you might make a Ruby app more 'efficient' (less memory, faster execution time - yeah I know requires are really fast anyways, but...) by only executing the requires method call *if* you really need it?

Comment: @Ash: I wouldn't say that's particularly likely. It's *possible*, but in most cases the penalty of executing require every time a method is called will outweigh any savings you might hope for. I have done it a couple of times, but only under pretty strange circumstances.

Comment: @Ash: Also, more importantly, it hurts readability. If a file is that expensive to require, that's probably an issue on its own. Not generally worth hurting readability for.

Comment: I wasn't doing it at the time of this question, but just very recently, I had a number of "provider" classes instantiated off the back of a config file. I was putting the requires in the instance loop, so as to not try and 'require' a file that wasn't used. I figured it was better for performance to only load what I actually needed, but it sounds that it might be better for future maintenance that I should just include them all anyways and not worry about the miniscule Memory and CPU consumption I might incur. Is that what your saying?

Comment: @Chuck I'm not much of a Ruby expert, but I found [this article](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/including_other_files_in_ruby.html) that conflicts with what you said. Basically - from what I can tell - Ruby will only require I file once, even if that require is called multiple times. I agree it is best to put `require` at the top of the file but is seems technically it would not affect the execution time. Now - I think -, if you were using `load`, that would be a different story.

Comment: @ChristianJuth: That is correct — the file will only be loaded once. I don't think that contradicts my answer. If you're talking about "the penalty of executing require " in my comment, I was talking about the penalty of actually executing require, which means Ruby has to resolve the method call, figure out what's actually being required and check whether it's already been loaded.

Comment: @Chuck yeah that is what I meant. That makes sense.

Answer (score 23):

at the top.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'fastercsv'

class MyClass
  # Do stuff with FasterCSV
end
```

Answer (score 14):

I can see a possible reason for not putting a `require` at the top of the file: where it's expensive to load and not always executed. One case that occurs to me is where, for example, code and its tests are in the same file, which is something I like to do from time to time for small library code in particular. Then I can run the file from my editor and the tests run. In this case when the file is `require`d in from elsewhere, I don't want `test/unit` to be loaded.

Something a little like this:

```
def some_useful_library_function()
  return 1
end

if __FILE__ == $0
  require 'test/unit'
  class TestUsefulThing < Test::Unit::TestCase
    def test_it_returns_1
      assert_equal 1, some_useful_library_function()
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 10):

It doesn't really matter where you put them, but if you put them *inside* a `class` or `module` expression, then it looks like you are importing whatever is in the `require`d file into the class's namespace, which is not true: everything ends up in the global namespace (or whatever namespaces are defined *in the library*).

So, better put them at the top to avoid any confusion.

Answer (score 4):

At the top of the file, the majority (but not all) languages handle imports this way. I find it much cleaner and easier to handle them this way.

I think it only makes sense this way really... like you get mid way in a file then:

```
class Foo
  def initialize(init_value)
    @instance_var = init_value

# some 500 lines of code later....

  end
end

class Bar
# oh look i need an import now!
require 'breakpoint'
```

as you can see, it would be very hard to track them. Not to mention if you wanted to use the imported functions **earlier in your code**, you would probably have to backtrack and include it again because the other import would be specific to that class. Importing the same files would create a lot of overhead during runtime as well.

Comment: It may not increase overhead. Not sure about ruby, but the importing of other modules in python is cached.

Answer (score 1):

I feel that the **require** statement belongs inside the class. Using classes means that we are accepting a basic tenet of OOP, namely objects should be as loosely coupled as possible. To me that implies minimizing external dependencies. If I later move a class to its own file, I don't want to have it break because I didn't track down all the necessary **require** statements that the class consumes.

It doesn't cause any problems to have duplicate **require** statements in a file and it simplifies the refactoring that inevitably is going to take place by the next programmer that inherit your code.

Answer (score 0):

Most answers recommend putting the *require* statements at the top of the file. However when requiring nested classes/modules you might want to consider putting them in the class instead (at the top). Have a look at this example:

```
# foo.rb
require './foo/bar'

class Foo < Struct.new(:name, :description)
  def bar
    Bar.new(self)
  end
end
```

```
# foo/bar.rb
class Foo
  class Bar < Struct.new(:foo)
  end
end
```

irb:

```
require './foo'
# ...
# TypeError (superclass mismatch for class Foo)
```

This happens because *Bar* is nested inside *Foo* and it will need to defined as such by nesting the *Bar* class inside the *Foo* class. However since *Foo* is not yet defined it is now being defined by the nested structure. After *Bar* is successfully required we now try to define the *Foo* class that inherits from another class. This fails due to the fact that *Foo* is already defined (by the nested structure) and inheritance can only occur on the initial definition of the class. Thus raising:

> TypeError (superclass mismatch for class Foo)

This issue can be resolved by simply moving the require statement inside the *Foo* class.