# Getting all Tweets from user x since date y with ruby?

Tags: ruby, twitter, tweets

I already have the twitter gem installed, but i cant find anything about how i can specify since when i want to collect the tweets. For example i want to have all tweets from user x in year 2016 - how do i specify that? Is that even possible, cause i cant find anything about it in the doc. 
In addition to that i read, that this might not be possible, cause twitter allows only the last 7 days? Is that really true ? 
In addition to that i would be interested in how to access tweets not by user but by hashtag, is that possible with the gem?

```
class TwitterGetter

  require 'twitter'

  client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
    config.consumer_key        = "xxxxx"
    config.consumer_secret     = "xxxx"
    config.access_token        = "xxxxx"
    config.access_token_secret = "xxxx"
  end
  tweets = client.user_timeline('Tweetaccount', count: 20)

  tweets.each { |tweet| puts tweet.full_text }
end

#https://www.rubyguides.com/2016/04/twitter-api-from-ruby-tutorial/
```

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but you should [place your `require` calls outside the class definition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605329/3784008). Also, if those are your actual keys, tokens, and secrets, then you're going to have to change them.

Comment: God damn, was a long day! Thank you so much, i changed it. But, why would you recommed to put the require calls outside of a class? just for code standards?

Comment: It's good that you removed the secrets, but since they're still visible in the revision history of your question you must make sure they're invalidated on the Twitter side. As for why `require` should be moved -- it's explained and discussed in the linked answer from my previous comment.

Comment: ah thanks! Yeah i regenerated them ;)

Comment: You want the `require` outside because it makes it clear what dependencies that file has, plus it forces the thing to require at start-up time and error out if there's a problem instead of exploding later on when you're not paying attention.

Answer (score 2):

Okay thank you all so much for your help! I think the solution is slightly different the syntax looks like this:

```
tweets = client.search("whatevertextiwanttomine", since: "2018-10-27", until: "2018-10-30")
```

It's a little strange that I couldn't use it to get to my last post, I'm not quite sure why yet. 
In any case, it doesn't seem possible to search posts older than 7 days with the normal Twitter Developer account.

Comment: That's correct. The standard search API is limited to 7 days. If you wanted to do this over a longer period you would need to use the premium 30 day or full archive search APIs (you can use these for free for a limited number of requests per month). I don't believe the gem you are using currently supports the premium APIs, but there's an alternative Ruby library [here](https://github.com/twitterdev/search-tweets-ruby) you might find useful

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [search](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/twitter/Twitter/REST/Search#search-instance_method) method of `twitter` gem. The [Twitter API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets) might be helpful as well.

```
client.search("from:Tweetaccount since:yyyy-mm-dd until:yyyy-mm-dd")
```

`since` should be start_date and `until` should be end_date.