# MailGun + Devise + Rails = "uninitialized constant MyMailer::MailGun"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, mailgun

I am using Devise for authentication and the [mailgun-ruby gem](https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-ruby) for sending email, and I am having difficulty figuring out how to make Devise's default mailer class work with Mailgun. Per the mailgun doc, I have configured my **production.rb** file to use mailgun settings:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :mailgun
config.action_mailer.mailgun_settings = {
 api_key: ENV['MAILGUN_API_KEY'],
 domain: 'mail.mywebsite.com'
}
```

And then in my mailer class, I require the gem and instantiate a `Mailgun::Client` object.

```
class MyMailer < Devise::Mailer
  require 'mailgun-ruby'
  helper :application
  include Devise::Controllers::UrlHelpers
  default template_path: 'users/mailer'

 def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts={})
  mg_client = MailGun::Client.new
  message_params = {
   from: "me@mywebsite.com",
   to: record.email,
   subject: "Please confirm your account"
  }

  mg_client.send_message message_params

  super
 end
end
```

I  commented out the `config.mailer = 'MyMailer'` line in the **devise.rb** initializer, but for some reason, Rails is looking for MailGun as a subclass of MyMailer. Why is this? The error is in the title - `uninitialized constant MyMailer::MailGun`.

Comment: Also, you need to move `require` outside of the class. Put it exactly at the top of the file.

Comment: you're the first person i've ever seen say this, and every code sample i've ever seen puts it inside the class. what is the benefit of putting it outside the class?

Comment: It's like convention for many programming languages. Developer can see which modules included by this class. Not sure is it making some difference for Rails. The only case I can imagine - loading of rarely used modules, it can save some memory, but I'm not 100% sure of this. UPD: here is some discussion about that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605261/do-ruby-require-statements-go-inside-or-outside-the-class-definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have a spelling in your code

```
mg_client = MailGun::Client.new
```

should be

```
mg_client = Mailgun::Client.new
```